# generate Array of random short in Java 8

Tags: arrays, random, java-8, java-stream, short

I found this code in a project:

```
public static Integer[] getArrayInt(int size, int numBytes) {
  return IntStream
      .range(0, size)
      .mapToObj(time -> {
        return extractValue(getArrayByte(numBytes * size), numBytes, time);
      }).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Integer[0]);
}

public static byte[] getArrayByte(int size) {
  byte[] theArray = new byte[size];
  new Random().nextBytes(theArray);
  return theArray;
}

private static int extractValue(byte[] bytesSamples, int numBytes, int time) {
  byte[] bytesSingleNumber = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesSamples, time * numBytes, (time + 1) * numBytes);
  int value = numBytesPerSample == 2
      ? (Byte2IntLit(bytesSingleNumber[0], bytesSingleNumber[1]))
      : (byte2intSmpl(bytesSingleNumber[0]));
  return value;
}

public static int Byte2IntLit(byte Byte00, byte Byte08) {
  return (((Byte08) << 8)
      | ((Byte00 & 0xFF)));
}

public static int byte2intSmpl(byte theByte) {
  return (short) (((theByte - 128) & 0xFF)
      << 8);
}
```

How to use it?

```
Integer[] coefficients = getArrayInt(4, 2);
```

The output:

```
coefficients: [8473, -12817, 12817, -20623]
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10189329/811293) for random short is attractive, but it needs both (positive and negative) in only one method).

Obviously is a long code for obtain the Array of Random short with stream.

*I know how to present a solution, with for loop and alternative method.*

**The Question**: What faster and optimized code in order to obtain it recommend to me?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.

Comment: It's not clear how all this posted code relates to the task "generate Array of random short in Java 8". The purpose of that code seems to be far away from that. Further, the phrase "but it needs both (positive and negative) in only one method" suggests that you didn't understood the linked answer, it provided two alternatives, you can pick from, depending on your needs. If the method is supposed to return positive and negative values, the 16 bit variant is what you need. As a side note, `extractValue` is horribly inefficient, performing an entirely obsolete array copy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clear and simple solution:

```
public static Integer[] getArrayInteger(int size) {
  return IntStream.generate(()
      -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(Short.MIN_VALUE, -Short.MIN_VALUE))
      .limit(size).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
}

public static Short[] getArrayShort(int size) {
  return IntStream.generate(()
      -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(Short.MIN_VALUE, -Short.MIN_VALUE))
      .limit(size).boxed().map(i -> i.shortValue())
      .toArray(Short[]::new);
}
```

`-Short.MIN_VALUE` like second argument in order to obtain `Short.MAX_VALUE` inclusive because the second argument for `nextInt` is exlusive.

Comment: This will throw an `InputMismatchException`, because the resulting `Integer[]` cannot be converted to `Short[]`.

Comment: `.boxed().map(i -> i.shortValue())` is performing an entirely obsolete boxing to `Integer` values, just `.mapToObj(i -> (short)i)` does the job much better. Besides that, using `ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(size, Short.MIN_VALUE, -Short.MIN_VALUE)` to create the `IntStream` is simpler and more efficient, especially when the terminal operation is `toArray`, as the implementation will utilize the already know size then.